# Accessing a S3 bucket through client code is denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to access and modify my s3 bucket through my web client. To do so, I've created a bucket and modified it in a way that it would allow public access.

My bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1646559824301",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1646559821897",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::airsoftarmory-user-inventory/*"
    }
]}
```

My CORS setting:

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "PUT",
        "HEAD",
        "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}]
```

ACL is enabled and looks like this:

[image]

For uploading an image to bucket, I created a new IAM user and a specific policy for `putObject` as follows:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::airsoftarmory-user-inventory/*"
    }
]
```

}

Used access keys of this user with policy attached inside my code.

The problem is, I am getting access denied response while both uploading and downloading. Can someone help me, what am I missing?

Comment: What is a public and private key? There is no such thing in aws. You mean aws access keys?

Comment: Yes. I meant access keys

Comment: But I don't think problem is with keys. I have access denied problem when downloading the image as well

Comment: ACLs are legacy. Don't use them. A bucket policy is sufficient for public download and IAM policies are sufficient for uploads. Check your Block Public Access settings. Check that you're using the correct IAM identity on your failed upload using the awscli (`aws sts get-caller-identity`).

Comment: I recommend that you 'test' the permissions by using the AWS CLI to upload/download the objects while using the same Access Key + Secret Key. That way, you are separating potential code problems from any IAM-related issues.

Answer (score 0):

For me to troubleshoot this problem.

1. I will check if aws has been configured properly. You could follow [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html), and could try `aws sts get-caller-identity` to check if credentials works properly.
2. The IAM role for the user is only given for `PutObject`, so this will not allow user to be able get any object out from the bucket. Try adding more permission to this user such as `GetObject` permission. This will give the user authority to pull out data from the bucket.
3. The bucket policy at the bucket only allow for `GetObject` and does not allow for any `PutObject`. Again try adding the `PutObject` action to the bucket policy. This might also be the problem facing now of not able to upload object to the bucket.

If you are confused with IAM and bucket policy. Try reading these blogs:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/
- https://binaryguy.tech/aws/s3/iam-policies-vs-s3-policies-vs-s3-bucket-acls/

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I said the bucket is public. That's why bucket policy allows GetObject. Even tho it allows GetObject, getting an image also returns access denied.

Comment: Ah great! Did you try granting more permission on your IAM role? Seems your IAM permission only allow `PutObject`